# ICOM IC-910h How much bandwidth does it listen when receiving USB and FM?

Tags: receiver, fm, ssb, icom, filter

CD-audio has a bandwidth of 22kHz. CW usually has a bandwidth between 3 to 5 kHz.

But I am wondering what is the bandwidth my Icom IC-910H can listen to in both, the SSB and the FM mode?

Also, what is the Bandwidth, the Icom IC-910H can transmit in USB and in FM?
Can the bandwidth be adjusted somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Icom's description](http://icomamerica.com/en/products/amateur/satellite/910h/specifications.aspx), the receiver's bandwidth is

> **Selectivity**
>
> **SSB, CW**
>   More than 2.8 kHz/-6dB;
>   Less than 4.2 kHz/-60 dB
>
> **FM**
>   More than 15.0 kHz/-6dB;
>   Less than 30 kHz/-60 dB
>
> **FM-N*2**
>   More than 6.0 kHz/-6dB;
>   Less than 18 kHz/-60 dB

A CW signal has a bandwidth of about 200 Hz. Therefore, [a narrower CW filter](http://icomamerica.com/en/products/amateur/satellite/910h/options.aspx) would significantly help the signal-to-noise ratio.

> FL-132/FL-133 **CW NARROW FILTERS**
>
> FL-132 is for the main band;
>   FL-133 is for the sub band operation. 
>   Center frequency: 10.8491 MHz (FL-132);
>   10.9491 MHz (FL-133). 
>   Passband width: 500 Hz/-6dB.

The instructions for installing the filter is in [the instruction manual](http://icomamerica.com/en/downloads/DownloadDocument.aspx?Document=32):

[image: Optional filter installation]

Comment: @SachaTholl You're welcome, but it is customary here to upvote **and** mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark next to the answer), rather than saying thanks in a comment. Doing that, then the person who answered also gets credit for it. :-)

Comment: Okay, I did it. Took a couple of time though :-)